# Using annotate to add different annotations to different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add panel labels to different facets in a plot.  I want them to be 1:7, but, the following code

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
     xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + opts(aspect.ratio = 1)

d1<-d + facet_wrap(~ color)

d1+annotate("text", x=0.25, y=1.5e+04, label=1:7)
```

yields

```
Error: When _setting_ aesthetics, they may only take one value. Problems: label
```

Now, I can supply a single value and get that replicated across all facets.  But how can I have different labels in different facets using annotate()?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With `annotate`, you can't. But by setting up a `data.frame` and using it as the data source for a `geom_text`, it is easy (with a few bookkeeping aspects).

```
d1 + geom_text(data=data.frame(x=0.25, y=1.5e+04, label=1:7, 
                               color=c("D","E","F","G","H","I","J")), 
               aes(x,y,label=label), inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to add text to multiple rows, make sure that your `colnames()` in the text `data.frame` match those of the data you are about to plot.