# modify stat_summary to also show count in distribution for box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

I have the boxplot below and I'd like to have the count as text.

```
group = c( rep(c(1,2,1),100)   )
group2 = rep(c("A","B","B"),100)
r = rnorm(300,50,63)
d = data.frame(  group = group,  r = r  , group2 = group2)
head(d)
custom= function (x){
  q = quantile(x)
  return(       c(q[1],q[3],q[5])  )}

ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=custom,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)+
  geom_text(data=      data.frame(x =  unique(as.factor(group))  , y = quantile(r[group])[3], label= paste0( "N=", length(r))   ),
            aes(x,y,label=label),inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~group2)
```

[image]

Currently the count is the same for each box plot.  how do I make it accuratly reflect the count in each box plot AND to not print when there is no boxplot like in group2 =A where there is no boxplot but count is still printed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 parts of my answer. The first is the original, non-facet answer. The 2nd is the facet answer.

**Part I**

```
library(ggplot2)
group = c( rep(c(1,2),100)   )
r = rnorm(200,50,63)
d = data.frame(  group = group,  r = r  )
head(d)

p <-
ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
               fun.args=list(probs=c(0,.5,1)),
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)

lb  <- paste("N = ", as.character(length(group[group==1])))
lb2 <- paste("N = ", as.character(length(group[group==2])))

p <- p   + annotate("text", x = 1, y = 40, label = lb) 
p   + annotate("text", x = 2, y = 40, label = lb2)
```

This is the best location on the chart for it and anyone who says otherwise is a fool*.

[image]

*Just kidding. It's subjective.

**Part II**

It seems we can't do this with `annotate` but we can do this with `geom_text`. I am a little short on time, but I will give you a template which should get you 99% of the way there (but which may need tweaking) and I will give you a link to a related answer.

I will also come back later and finish tweaking the code below.

```
group = c( rep(c(1,2),100)   )
group2 = rep(c("A","B"),100)
r = rnorm(200,50,63)
d = data.frame(  group = group,  r = r  , group2 = group2)
head(d)
custom= function (x){
  q = quantile(x)
  c = length(x)
  return(       c(q[1],q[3],q[5], q[5]*1.1 )  )}


ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=custom,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)+
  facet_wrap(~group2)

label <- as.character()
for(i in unique(group)){
  label[i] <- as.character(paste("N = ", length(group[group == i])))
}

data=data.frame(x=1.1, y=1.5e+02, label=label, group2 = c("A", "B"))

p + geom_text(data=data, 
               aes(data$x,data$y,label=data$label), inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[Using annotate to add different annotations to different facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023129/using-annotate-to-add-different-annotations-to-different-facets)

Comment: but that solution requires manually setting the x and y values of the annotation. I am looking for a solutions that will not need to be recoded  because there may be 10,20 aor 30 boxplots. ANd in my case I am using facet too. I will update the code with the faceting.

Comment: @user3022875 If you can give me an example with 30 box plots I can give you an example of how to manage it

Comment: see the example above that has 1 boxplot in 2 plots using facet

Comment: @user3022875 OK just give me a minute and I'll make update my answer with the new plot. If you want to have a large number then it would really be best to include it in the example so that I can make sure my answer is adequate though (10 or 20, etc).

Comment: @user3022875 Hey, ok so I updated my answer. I have to go to an appointment, but I gave you a link that should solve this and my work-in-progress code that implements the ideas on that link and I'll come back very soon to finish updating this code if you need me to. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023129/using-annotate-to-add-different-annotations-to-different-facets