# adding text to facet plot blank entry and label error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add text to a facet plot

```
group = c( rep(c(1,2,1),100)   )
group2 = rep(c("A","B","B"),100)
r = rnorm(300,50,63)
d = data.frame(  group = group,  r = r  , group2 = group2)
head(d)
custom= function (x){
  q = quantile(x)
  return(       c(q[1],q[3],q[5])  )}

p = ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)+
  facet_wrap(~group2)
p
```

that code produces this plot:

Why is there a blank entry for group 2 in class A? Running unique() below you can see there is no group = 2 for class A

```
unique(d[,c('group2','group')])
```

[image]

Next I want to add the count as text over each box plot so i was following this technique:  [Using annotate to add different annotations to different facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023129/using-annotate-to-add-different-annotations-to-different-facets)

I use a loop over the unique combinations of group2 and group to make a data frame with the labels and then add the labels as text to the plot.

```
un=unique(d[,c('group2','group')])
n = dim(un)[1]
un$lab = ""
for(i in 1:dim(un)[1])
{
  un$lab  = length(d$r[group == un$group[i] & group2 == un$group2[i]])
}
un$group2 = as.factor(un$group2)
str(un)
un
p + geom_text(data = un,label = un$lab)
```

BUt i get this error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): x, y
```

Any idea how to eliminate the blank entry and show the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for you first question about the blank in panel A try this : `facet_wrap(~group2, scales = "free_x")`

The error message you are getting is ggplot complaining that it doesn't know how to orient your new layer `geom_text()` into the existing plot framework because `un` doesn't have the `r` column you originally mapped for `y` coordinates. If you specify it like this:
`geom_text(data = un, aes(x = group, y = 50, label = lab))` it will work but you might need to play around with the alignment a bit (I was lazy and used 50).

So in conclusion this is your plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(factor(group), r)) + 
  geom_boxplot()    +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile,
             aes(label=sprintf("%1.0f", ..y..)),
             position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3)+
  facet_wrap(~group2, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_text(data = un, aes(x = group, y = 50, label = lab))
```