# Adding Text to a Facet Grid

Tags: r

I am till having trouble with this, so I have edited my question (below) to include my data.

I would like to add two different labels (the respective sample sizes) to each of the sections of the grid.

I know I need to use geom_text, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Everything I have tried has returned errors. Here is the code I used to make my graph so far:

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(y = Rating, x = week, group= StudentFactor, colour=StudentFactor))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Type ~.)+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x), colour= "black", aes(group=1), se= FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs (x= "Week", y="Rating of Q: Seniors Supportive vs. Supporting First Years")
```

Someone mentioned that it might be helpful if I included the following:

```
> dput(Q)
structure(list(StudentFactor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L), .Label = c("789331", 
"796882", "805933", "826523", "827911", "830271", "831487", "832929", 
"834598", "836364", "838607", "839802", "841903", "843618", "852125", 
"855524", "873527", "876406", "879972", "885409", "885650", "888712", 
"894218", "903303", "928026", "952797", "955389", "956952", "957206", 
"957759", "959200", "962490", "965873", "967416", "968728", "969005"
), class = "factor"), Question = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Q", "Q10", "Q12", "Q2", "Q8"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FYS", 
    "SNR"), class = "factor"), week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 
    9L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    9L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 8L), Rating = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, -2, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, -1, -3, 2, 0, 0, 
    -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, 
    0, 4, -3, 1, 1, -1, -2, 0, 2, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 
    1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
    1, -1, -3, 3, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    -1, 1, -1, 0, -2, 2, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-231L), .Names = c("StudentFactor", "Question", "Type", "week", 
"Rating"))
```

---

Earlier Question:

I have used the following code to make this graph:

[image]

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(y = Rating, x = week, group= StudentFactor, colour=StudentFactor))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Q$Type ~.)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", aes(group=1))+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs (x= "Week", y="Rating of Q: Seniors Supportive vs. Supporting First Years")
```

However, as soon as I try to add an annotation to include the sample size for each cohort, I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 231 rows, data has 1
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(y = Rating, x = week, group= StudentFactor, colour=StudentFactor))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Q$Type ~.)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", aes(group=1))+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs (x= "Week", y="Rating of Q: Seniors Supportive vs. Supporting First Years")+
  annotate("text", x = 1, y=4, label = "N=")
```

I am a complete beginner at R. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a small subset of data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @steveb
I have added a subset of my data! Thanks!

Comment: In the future, you will likely get faster help if you paste in the output of `dput` as in `dput(my_data_frame)`.  One can then use that output to quickly create the same `data.frame` locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you would like to label each panel with the respective sample size, or to add the total sample size just in one place. In that case `annotate` will be of no use (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023129/using-annotate-to-add-different-annotations-to-different-facets)), but you can use `geom_text` instead:

You would create a separate `data.frame` for your labels, which you then use inside of `geom_text`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

labels <- tibble::tribble(~mpg, ~hp, ~cyl, ~label,
                          15, 200, 4, "label 1",
                          15, 150, 6, "label 2")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(label = label))
```

[image]

(Since you didn't provide data which would make it possible to reproduce your graphs, I simply used `mtcars` to illustrate the problem.)

### Edit:

Using your data I adapted the code. First you create a `data.frame` for your label(s):

```r
labels <- data.frame(
  x = 2.5,
  y = 3,
  Type = "FYS",
  label = "mylabel"
)
```

Then you simply add the following line to your code:

```r
... +
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

This approach is slightly different than what I showed above: Either you supply the coordinates according to your variables, which you use in the rest of the plot, or you give them new names, use `inherit.aes = FALSE` and set the new variables with `aes` as demonstrated with your data.

Full code:

```r
labels <- data.frame(
  x = 2.5,
  y = 3,
  Type = "FYS",
  label = "mylabel"
)

ggplot(data = Q, mapping = aes(y = Rating, x = week, group= StudentFactor, colour=StudentFactor))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Type ~ .)+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x), colour= "black", aes(group=1), se= FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs (x= "Week", y="Rating of Q: Seniors Supportive vs. Supporting First Years") +
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I have added my data to the question as I am still having difficulty. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to using `facet_grid` incorrectly. Replace your line with `facet_grid(Type ~.)+` instead of `Q$Type`. For example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(iris$Species ~ .) + 
  annotate("text", x = 7, y = 4, label = "foo")
```

> `Error in '$<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
>     replacement has 150 rows, data has 1`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(Species ~ .) + 
  annotate("text", x = 7, y = 4, label = "foo")
```

No error:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make it so the label can be different on each section of the grid, or alternatively only appear on one section?