# ggplot2: Can I add the strip labels to every plot with facet_grid()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

Here is a typical case for using multiple variables in the rows or columns in `facet_grid()`.
[image]

My question is how can I add the strip labels to every plot? For instance, the second row only contains the strip label "f" in the y-axis. I need all six plots all get two strip labels in X and Y.

I am new to ggplot2 and R, I hope you can help me. Thank you all so much.

Comment: try `facet_wrap` instead?

Comment: I don't think you can. If you need to label each plot individually, possible workarounds would be to [annotate a title inside each facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023129/using-annotate-to-add-different-annotations-to-different-facets), or make multiple plots and combine them using 'gridExtra` or `cowplot`.